# Abrir formulario con los datos de la fila que tiene el ID seleccionado o con un botón

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente código de Google apps script, donde se abre un formulario de edición. La hoja de cálculo dispone de 3 columnas: Id, Nombre y teléfono. El id es numérico y se genera automáticamente.

¿Cómo podría abrir el formulario que visualice los datos de la fila del Id que haya seleccionado en la hoja de cálculo o bien pulsando un botón para luego editar el campo que desee y enviarlo a la hoja?
Por ejemplo, selecciono el id 2 y abro el formulario, que viene con ID 2, Nombre Manu y teléfono 321521, tal como muestra la imágen. Luego edito campos y botón EDIT. Los datos de dicha fila se modifican.
[image: Abrir imagen con los datos de la fila seleccionada (ID: 2]

**Code.gs**

```
function editUserForm(){
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("editForm")
var html = template.evaluate();
html
.setTitle("My Edit Form")
.setHeight(400)
.setWidth(400);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
.showModelessDialog(html, "Edita tus Datos");
 }
```

**editForm.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>`
   <html>
   <head>
   <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
   <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">code</i>
    <input id="ideform" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="ideform">Id</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
     <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="username">Nombre</label>
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col s12">
     <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
     <input id="tel" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="icon_telephone">Telefono</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="btn">edit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
     </div>
     </div><!--END ROW-->

      </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"> 
    </script>

   <script>
 
  var phoneBox = document.getElementById("tel");
  var nameBox = document.getElementById("username");
 
 document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",editRecord);

function editRecord(){

var name = nameBox.value;
var phone = phoneBox.value;


 if(name.trim().length == 0 || phone.trim().length == 0){
    
    M.toast({html: 'Nombre y Telefono Requeridos !!....', classes: 'rounded'});

    }else{
 
      var data = {
      name: nameBox.value,
      phone: phoneBox.value
      };
      google.script.run.appendData(data);
      nameBox.value = "";
      phoneBox.value ="";
   }//close else
}//close addRecord

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Es [Salva Solbes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112785/salva-solbes) otra cuenta tuya? Si es así, te sugiero solicitar la "combinación de cuentas". Los detalles se indican en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts. Por otro lado si la respuesta te ha servido no olvides que puedes aceptarla, votarla, dejar un comentario para solicitar alguna aclaración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta tienes dos partes principales

1. Leer los datos de la fila seleccionada y pasar estos al formulario
2. Escribir los datos en la fila que corresponda según el id seleccionado.

Para la primera parte, el script debe leer los datos, esto se hace con `getValues()` y luego pasarlos al formulario. Como estás haciendo uso de `createTemplateFromFile` podrías incluir en el HTML scriptlets

Para la segunda parte deberás implementar un algoritmo que encuentre la fila con el ID y usar esta fila para actualizar los datos según corresponda. En un algoritmo muy básico podrías asumir que la posición (columna) nunca va a cambiar, en un algoritmo más robusto podrías determinar la posición con base en los encabezados de la misma.

Recursos

- [HTML Service: Templated HTM](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)